# How can a bash script task in Azure DevOps Pipelines access Service Connection?

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, serviceconnection

I am using 'run a bash script' task in my azure yaml pipeline. I need to access service connection ( docker connection) within the script so I can login to docker & jfrog and logout multiple times ( without having to use variables or variable groups) .

How can I achieve this? Appreciate your suggestions & help in advance

Comment: when you said docker, you mean container registry ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way that you used to access the service connection in your bash. If you use the [`System.AccessToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken), the permission of the token is corresponding to the `Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName})` or `{Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name})`, depending on the [job authorization scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#job-authorization-scope).

Then add the specific identity to the `Security` of the service connection.

[image]

[image]

If you use other ways to auth, you can also add the corresponding identity with the permission you want.